# Как посмотреть что хранится в php://output?

Tags: php, phpstorm, openserver, xdebug

Делаю проверку и отладку с помощью xDebug.
OpenServer + xDebug + phpStorm.

Как посмотреть что хранится в php://output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[ob_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ob-get-contents.php)** — Возвращает содержимое буфера вывода

Пример использования

```
<?php

ob_start();

echo "Привет ";

$out1 = ob_get_contents();

echo "Мир";

$out2 = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();

var_dump($out1, $out2);
```

Результат

```
string(6) "Привет "
string(11) "Привет Мир"
```

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным.

Comment: а давайте `php.net` скопируем сюда. В данный момент это единственно достоверный ресурс который поддерживает все версии **php** . Методы которые считаются устаревшими не удаляются а помечаются соотвествующие. Так что даже если дублировать информацию с подобных ресурсов теоретически метод может быть изменен и информация об этом, а скопированная информация так и останется не достоверной

Comment: Не надо дублировать всю страницу, но ответ был бы лучше с коротким отмечением функции и примером использования, чтобы будущие зрители этого ответа могли узнать нужная информация быстрее.

Comment: @username, вы видно никогда не сталкивались со ссылками, которые упоминаются в старых ответах на so и которые больше недействительны. Поэтому небольшую выдержку с примером кода было бы неплохо добавить

Comment: для работы данного метода используются еще два метода. примеры и описание их тоже сюда?

Comment: Если хотите, но не надо всё объяснить. Например, "что значит `echo`" - это уже слишком много деталей.

Comment: Ответ то в принце позволяет так дебажить. Но не позволяет в процессе выполнения программы в режиме debug просматривать содержимое. Для этого придется много раз выгружать данные из php://output.

Где есть более подробная информация про php://output?
Предполагаю, что это все таки какой-то временный файл. Кто знает?

Comment: а что Вы выгружая `php://output` дебажите?